# How make AND and OR wordpress query

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

I made a (taxonomy) query with relation OR and that works.

But I have a couple of filters that I woud combine.

Then I should use AND (relation) but when the visitor not set an filter (in dropdown see filter) than query shows nothing.

How to make a query with AND and OR function?

```
$taxonomy1 = $_GET['soort'];
$taxonomy2 = $_GET['merk'];
$taxonomy3 = $_GET['hefcapaciteit'];
$taxonomy4 = $_GET['brandstof'];

$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
           'taxonomy' => 'soort',
           'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
           'terms' => $taxonomy1,

        ),
        array(
           'taxonomy' => 'merk',
           'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
           'terms' => $taxonomy2,

        ),
        array(
           'taxonomy' => 'hefcapaciteit',
           'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
           'terms' => $taxonomy3,

        ),
        array(
           'taxonomy' => 'brandstof',
           'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
           'terms' => $taxonomy4,

        ),
    ),  
));

?>

<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();  ?>
```

Below the filter:

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/zoek" method="get">
   <div class="large-12 medium-12 columns select">
      <?php wp_dropdown_categories('taxonomy=soort&order=ASC&show_option_none=Soort&name=soort'); ?>
      <?php wp_dropdown_categories('taxonomy=merk&order=ASC&show_option_none=Merk&name=merk'); ?>
      <?php wp_dropdown_categories('taxonomy=hefcapaciteit&order=ASC&show_option_none=Hefcapaciteit&name=hefcapaciteit'); ?>
      <?php wp_dropdown_categories('taxonomy=brandstof&order=ASC&show_option_none=Brandstof&name=brandstof'); ?>
      <a href="/occasions" class="button blauw">reset</a>  
      <input type="submit" class="button" value="zoek">  
   </div>
</form>
```